# Compilation error with generics and closure to initialize a class instance

Tags: swift

What I am trying to do is to **inject a closure into a class initializer so that I can control its initialization** from outside.

I've defined a protocol which must be implemented by the classes I want to initialize:

```
protocol EntityInitializable {
    typealias T : EntityInitializable
    init(initializer: (T) -> ())
}
```

and a function attempting to inject the closure

```
class EntityMapper<T : EntityInitializable> {
    func f() -> T {
        var cb = {(entity: T) -> () in
        }

        return T(cb)
    }
}
```

This generates the following error during compilation:

> error: cannot convert the expression's type 'T.T' to type 'T'
>           return T(cb)

If I modify the above code removing the generics part, such as:

```
class MyClass {
    init(initializer: (MyClass) -> ()) {
    }
}

class EntityMapper {
    func f() -> MyClass {
        var cb = {(entity: MyClass) -> () in
        }

        return MyClass(cb)
    }
}
```

it works.

Any idea about what's wrong? Is it perhaps because I am trying to make recursive use of generics, by creating an instance of a generic and passing a closure with a parameter of the same generic type?

Comment: Those T are really confusing, you should really give meaningful names to your type parameters. While in generics for brevity the use of T is accepted, if not encouraged, when defining typealiases it's better to give them a name that makes it clear what the type stand for (imagine if someone else had to implement that protocol, how would she be able to understand what type to use?)

Comment: That's correct and I agree from a usage perspective - but often during development when I see T or V I immediately know it's a generic, whereas using a more meaningful name it's not so obvious...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that your code doesn't work is that there is nothing that says the `T` in 
EntityInitializable (for clarity I'll call it `EntityType` from here on) must be equal to the type that implements the protocol. Here's an example that should shed some light on the issue:

```
class A: EntityInitializable {
    typealias EntityType = B
    init(initializer: (EntityType) -> ()) {

    }
}

class B: EntityInitializable {
    // [...]
}
```

This is perfectly fine according to the code you wrote and it's the reason why the compiler doesn't accept the `cb` closure. Its `entity` parameter has type `T`, while `EntityInitializable` expect its type to be `T.EntityType`.

The right way to write this code is by using `Self` which represents the class that implements the protocol:

```
protocol EntityInitializable {
    init(initializer: (Self) -> ())
}
```

Comment: Interesting... I haven't found any mention of `Self` in the documentation, do you have any link?

Comment: No, but the documentation of Swift at the moment is incomplete at best, especially about metaprogramming. `Self` is used through out all the builtin protocols of the language, though. Try for example to write Equatable in an Xcode window and Cmd-click on it.

Comment: Thanks - tested and it works. Need to dig into that now, I wanna know more